# Secured password field not secured on release

Tags: react-native

So i have a form that seems to act different on an iOS release build than a debug build. Here's a screenshot showing:

[image: release vs debug]

```
<React.Fragment>
  <View>
    <FormInput
      label="username"
      value={values.username}
      name="username"
      onChange={setFieldValue}
      onTouch={setFieldTouched}
      error={touched.username && errors.username}
    />
    <FormInput
      label="password"
      secureTextEntry={true}
      value={values.password}
      textContentType='password'
      name="password"
      onChange={setFieldValue}
      onTouch={setFieldTouched}
      error={touched.password && errors.password}
    />
    <Button
      block
      style={styles.loginButton}
      onPress={handleSubmit}
      disabled={!isValid || isSubmitting}
    >
      <Text>Submit</Text>
    </Button>
  </View>
</React.Fragment>
```

The password field isn't being obfuscated, the text hints aren't visible and the submit button doesn't work. Any one know if there's some funky flag going on that would change the feature?

Comment: Which package are you using?

Comment: im using FormInput and Formik, along with Yup

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this specific problem but I can offer some generic advice.

Whenever I have discrepancies in my release and debug builds I follow these steps and it tends to work well:

```
in Xcode:
  do cmd+shift+alt+k  (cleans build folder)

in terminal:
  watchman watch-del-all
  rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-*
  rm -rf node_modules
  yarn cache clean
  yarn install
```

Sometimes you need to fully quit Xcode, and you might also try a system restart. Hope this helps, good luck!